# Latex error during make

Tags: errors, compiling

`make -C doc html latexpdf` 
yields this:

```
Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
Writing index file Arakoon.idx
(./Arakoon.aux)
Runaway argument?
{{1.10.3}{9}{Client side support\relax }{subsection.1.10.
! File ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.113 \begin{document}

?
```

any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The aux file is corrupt delete it (make clean might do that with a bit of luck:-) and re-make

Comment: This qn is a duplicate of the SO qn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304127/make-error-latex.  The question has some general interest, despite the lack of an MWE, since the error is [fairly widely cited in pleas for help](https://google.com/search?q="File%20ended%20while%20scanning%20use%20of%20%5C%40newl%40bel"), and (ii) the error message contains enough information to give a useful response (cf. @DavidCarlisle's comment).

Answer (score 2):

This error message is normally due to an unclosed `{` somewhere (my personal favorite way of doing that is in `\frac{...}{...}`, particularly with complex expressions). Sometimes this happens inside some package's macros because some construction they don't like (say an equation in `\(...\)` inside a title or caption can give you something like this). Look carefully at where you use the text cited by the message. Some constructions in references don't work, you can use `\texorpdfstring{}` to replace problematic stuff with alternative text.

If you have an intelligent editor, place yourself near the end of the file, and enter `}`, the editor should tell you where it is opened.

Comment: It looks to me like a non-robust command in a subsubsection heading, generating junk in the .aux file.  The "intelligent" editor is going to point at `\begin{document}`, which does not really cast light on the matter.

Comment: I have the same thing happen when I compile with TexShop on my Mac, after getting an error once, the next time I run the code I get this error until I delete the aux file and run it again